# How to add an item to the Powerpont context menu using .net add-in project

Tags: c#, powerpoint, excel-addins, office-addins

I've never wrote an office-plugin before, and I'd like to add my-own functionality to Powerpoint.
I want to add an item to the context menu that pops-out when the user select a slide,
an when this item is selected - i want to launch .net form.
I'd appreciate any reference you may have, or a sample code !
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is article about [customizing context menu in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862.aspx), and I think it's also applicable to PowerPoint.

Another guide: [Customizing contextmenu in Office 2010!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832.aspx)

[image]

Have fun :)

Comment: If I do not want to add new items to the menu, is it possible to intercept click or attach some extra handler to existing item in context menu e.g. I want to execute MyCustomMethod() when user clicks on "Paragraph" in the menu, is it possible?

Comment: I can't say exactly because I just developed a small outlook add-in with custom ribbon. You may check this link https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/02/27/how-an-office-add-in-intercepts-clicking-a-built-in-control/